# GCC C++ "Hello World" program -> .exe is 500kb big when compiled on Windows. How can I reduce its size?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, netbeans, size

I just recently started learning C++ - I am using [nuwen's](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) version of MingW on Windows, using NetBeans as an IDE (I have also MSDN AA Version of MSVC 2008, though I don't use it very often).

When compiling this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dog, cat, bird, fish;

void f(int pet) {
  cout << "pet id number: " << pet << endl;
}

int main() {
  int i, j, k;
  cout << "f(): " << (long)&f << endl;
  cout << "dog: " << (long)&dog << endl;
  cout << "cat: " << (long)&cat << endl;
  cout << "bird: " << (long)&bird << endl;
  cout << "fish: " << (long)&fish << endl;
  cout << "i: " << (long)&i << endl;
  cout << "j: " << (long)&j << endl;
  cout << "k: " << (long)&k << endl;
} ///:~
```

my executable was about 1MB big. When I changed project configuration from *Debug* to *Release*, used -O1 -Os flags ( stripping debugging symbols along the way ), binary size was reduced from 1MB to 544KB.

I am not a "size freak", but I am just wondering - is there any way, that I could reduce .exe size even more? I just think, that 544KB is just too much for such a simple application ).

Comment: Totally unrelated but you should use reinterpret_cast or static_cast over a C-style cast.

Comment: -O1 -Os is redundant. Only the last -O option is used.

Comment: When my "Hello, World" programs are too large, I optimise them to "Hi, World".

Comment: When I compiled this program, removing #include <iostream> and adding #include <cstdio>, replacing cout's with printf's and endl's with "\n" - compiled exe reduced it's size from 544KB to 6KB! I am surprised. Is this ok to write c++ programs this way if I don't need all the features provided by <iostream>?

Comment: @liori but that's static linkage with the runtime though which is kind of cheating.

Comment: How is this a "hello, world" program?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The problem here is not so much with the library as it is with the way the
library is linked. Granted, *iostream* is a moderately huge library but I don't
think it can be so huge as to cause a program to generate an executable that is
`900KB` larger than a similar one that uses `C` functions. The one to blame
is not `iostream` but `gcc`. More accurately, `static linking` is to be blamed.

How would you explain these results(with your program):

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe              SIZE: 935KB
gcc test.cpp -o test.exe -lstdc++     SIZE: 64.3KB
```

Different sizes of executables are being generated with exactly the same
build options.

The answer lies in the way **gcc** links the object files.
When you compare the outputs from these two commands:

```
g++ -v test.cpp -o test.exe // c++ program using stream functions  
gcc -v test.c -o test.exe   // c program that using printf
```

you'll find out that the only places they differ(apart from the paths to the
temporary object files) is in the options used:

```
   C++(iostream) | C(stdio)
-------------------------------
-Bstatic         |  (Not There)
-lstdc++         |  (Not There)
-Bdynamic        |  (Not There)
-lmingw32        | -lmingw32 
-lgcc            | -lgcc 
-lmoldname       | -lmoldname 
-lmingwex        | -lmingwex 
-lmsvcrt         | -lmsvcrt 
-ladvapi32       | -ladvapi32 
-lshell32        | -lshell32 
-luser32         | -luser32 
-lkernel32       | -lkernel32 
-lmingw32        | -lmingw32 
-lgcc            | -lgcc 
-lmoldname       | -lmoldname 
-lmingwex        | -lmingwex 
-lmsvcrt         | -lmsvcrt
```

You've got your culprit right there at the top. `-Bstatic` is the option that comes
exactly after the object file which may look something like this:

```
"AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccMUlPac.o" -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic ....
```

If you play around with the options and remove 'unnecessary' libraries,
you can reduce the size of the executable from `934KB` to `4.5KB` max
in my case. I got that `4.5KB` by using `-Bdynamic`, the `-O` flag
and the most crucial libraries that your application can't live without, i.e
`-lmingw32`, `-lmsvcrt`, `-lkernel32`. You'll get a **25KB** executable at that
point. Strip it to **10KB** and **UPX** it to around `4.5KB-5.5KB`.

Here's a Makefile to play with, for kicks:

```
## This makefile contains all the options GCC passes to the linker
## when you compile like this: gcc test.cpp -o test.exe
CC=gcc

## NOTE: You can only use OPTIMAL_FLAGS with the -Bdynamic option. You'll get a
## screenfull of errors if you try something like this: make smallest type=static
OPTIMAL_FLAGS=-lmingw32 -lmsvcrt -lkernel32

DEFAULT_FLAGS=$(OPTIMAL_FLAGS) \
-lmingw32 \
-lgcc \
-lmoldname \
-lmingwex \
-lmsvcrt \
-ladvapi32 \
-lshell32 \
-luser32 \
-lkernel32 \
-lmingw32 \
-lgcc  \
-lmoldname \
-lmingwex \
-lmsvcrt


LIBRARY_PATH=\
-LC:\MinGW32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1 \
-LC:\mingw32\lib\gcc \
-LC:\mingw32\lib\mingw32\lib \
-LC:\mingw32\lib\

OBJECT_FILES=\
C:\MinGW32\lib\crt2.o \
C:\MinGW32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\crtbegin.o

COLLECT2=C:\MinGW32\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\collect2.exe

normal:
    $(CC) -c test.cpp
    $(COLLECT2) -Bdynamic $(OBJECT_FILES)  test.o -B$(type) -lstdc++ -Bdynamic  $(DEFAULT_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATH) -o test.exe

optimized:
    $(CC) -c -O test.cpp
    $(COLLECT2) -Bdynamic $(OBJECT_FILES)  test.o -B$(type) -lstdc++ -Bdynamic  $(DEFAULT_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATH) -o test.exe

smallest:
    $(CC) -c -O test.cpp
    $(COLLECT2) -Bdynamic $(OBJECT_FILES)  test.o -B$(type) -lstdc++ -Bdynamic  $(OPTIMAL_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATH) -o test.exe

ultimate:
    $(CC) -c -O test.cpp
    $(COLLECT2) -Bdynamic $(OBJECT_FILES)  test.o -B$(type) -lstdc++ -Bdynamic  $(OPTIMAL_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATH) -o test.exe
    strip test.exe
    upx test.exe

CLEAN:
    del *.exe *.o
```

Results(YMMV):

```
// Not stripped or compressed in any way
make normal    type=static     SIZE: 934KB
make normal    type=dynamic    SIZE: 64.0KB

make optimized type=dynamic    SIZE: 30.5KB
make optimized type=static     SIZE: 934KB

make smallest  type=static     (Linker Errors due to left out libraries)
make smallest  type=dynamic    SIZE: 25.6KB 

// Stripped and UPXed
make ultimate type=dynamic    (UPXed from 9728 bytes to 5120 bytes - 52.63%)
make ultimate type=static     (Linker Errors due to left out libraries)
```

A possible reason for the inclusion of `-Bstatic` in the default build options
is for better performance. I tried building `astyle` with `-Bdynamic` and got
a speed decrease of 1 second on average, even though the application was way
smaller than the original(400KB vs 93KB when UPXed).

Answer (score 24):

The

```
#include <iostream>
```

causes a lot of the standard library to be linked in, at least with g++. If you are really concerned about executable size, try replacing all uses of iostreams with printf or similar. This will typically give you a smaller, faster executable (I got yours down to about 6K) at the cost of convenience and type-safety.

Comment: In a C program, I did not include any include files and just main() was there with one variable definition. Even then the size of text segment was 10628. So that means internally something gets added. What are they?

Answer (score 11):

Not sure how much use it will be to you, but [someone has done quite a lot of work on reducing the size of a simple Windows .exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20111214171623/http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/).

They were able to create a simple .exe that will execute on a modern version of Windows in 133 bytes, by using some very extreme methods.

Comment: Maybe not directly related with his question, but thanks a lot for sharing your find!

Comment: Equivalent exercise for Linux ELF files: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Answer (score 9):

You could use -s, which I believe is built into mingw as well.
A simple hello world application compiled using g++ 3.4.4 on cygwin produced executable that was 476872 bytes, compiling again with -s (strips unnecessary data), reduced the same executable to 276480 bytes.

The same hello world application on cygwin using g++ 4.3.2 produced an executable of 16495 bytes, using strip reduced the size to 4608 bytes.
As far as I can see, probably best to use more recent version of g++.

MingW has just released gcc 4.4.0, so if the executable size is important then I'd consider using that. As it indicates -s will probably help strip much of the debugging information out for you, that is only recommended if it is for production use.

Comment: Did you actually try out your example of using std::cout instead?  I don't think that has any effect at all on the final exe, it just means that you can type a shorter name in the source.

Comment: This is more likely a cygwin vs mingw difference, than gcc 3.x vs 4.x.

Answer (score 8):

You get the C++ standard library, and other stuff I guess, statically linked in as mingw has its own implementation of these libraries.

Don't worry so much about it, when you make more complex program, the size won't grow accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there's not really anything you can do to reduce that .exe size with a base distribution of mingw. 550kb is about as small as you can get it, because mingw and gcc/g++ in general are bad at stripping unused functions. About 530kb of that is from the msvcrt.a library.

If you really wanted to get into it, you might be able to rebuild the msvcrt.a library with -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections compiler options, and then use the -Wl,--gc-sections linker options when linking your app, and this should be able to strip a lot of that stuff out of there. But if you're just learning C++, rebuilding that library may be a bit advanced.

Or you could just use MSVC, which is great at stripping unused functions. That same bit of code compiled with MSVC produces a 10kb exe.

Comment: FWIW GCC 4.5 (MinGW in my case) gives a 10kb file, possibly down to Link Time Optimization (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html)

Comment: I tried lto and got very little improvement (10%). It may not be as simple as just adding extra options though

Answer (score 3):

You could always run [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) on your exe after you have created it.

Answer (score 3):

If you need small executables, Tiny C will compile a 1536 bytes executable for a printf("Hello world!")
TinyC is only C, not C++ and is known to compile faster and give slower executables than gcc.

EDITED:
I have just tried a cout<"Hello World!" in DevC++ (bundles Mingw 4.8 and an Ide) and i got a 4,5 MB executable!!

Answer (score 2):

Well when you use C++ standard library, exe can get big really quickly. If after stripping debug symbol, you still want to reduce the size of your software, you can use a packer like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/). But, be warned, some antivirus choke on exe packed with UPX as some virus used it a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I replicated your test using Cygwin and g++.  Your code compiled to 480k with -O2.  Running *strip* on the executable reduced it to 280k.

In general, though, I suspect your problem is the use of the <iostream> header.  This causes a fairly large library to be linked in.  Also, note that `cout << x` does a lot more than just printing.  There are locales and streams and all sorts of under-the-hood stuff.

If however, having a small executable size is a real, mission-critical objective, then avoid it and use printf or puts.  If it's not, then I would say pay the one-time cost of iostream and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the "nm" utility or some other program that shows whats in your .exe, you'll see that it contains tons of classes that someone *might* want to use, but that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

How is it that other compilers like msvc8 or even an order compiler like borland c++ 5.5.1 are capable of producing very small executables but mingw gcc isn't able to?

I did a quick compile of a 'hello world' for each of the following 
toolsets and observed the compiled executable size. Please note that in 
all these cases the runtime library is statically linked and all debug 
symbols have been stripped:

```
compiler toolchain            exe size                   exe size
                              (w/iostream header)        (w/cstdio printf)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Borland C++ 5.5.1             110kbyte                    52kbyte
MSVC 2008 express             102kbyte                    55kbyte
MinGW- GCC 3.4.5              277kbyte                    <10kbyte
MinGW- GCC 4.4.1              468kbyte                    <10kbyte
```

What's interesting is the later version of gcc 4.4.1 produces an even larger executable than gcc3.4.5, probably due to different version of libstdc++.

So is there really no way to remove dead code during the linking phase for mingw?

Comment: You sure you're not getting MSVC confused with MinGW? MSVC would make 10kb exe.

Answer (score 0):

The major part of the size stems from the use of fairly extensive runtime libraries.
So in real life you are actually linking a very large piece of 'dead code' if you have such a simple application.

As far as I know there are no linker flags to skip the unused parts of a linked library.

There are two ways I know of to fake a smaller application:

1. Use dynamic linking. Then your application refers to the dynamically loaded library. You still need the full size (actually more) but you have a much smaller executable.
2. Use an [executable compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression) system.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but maybe helpful for new c++ users that ended here searching for "*reducing hello world binary size*":

Here's the steps I've done to compile a `hello_world.exe` with ~20KB:

## hello_world.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>  // not <iostream>
int main()
{
 printf("Hello, World");
 return 0;
}
```

## g++ cmd line

```
g++ -s hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.exe
```

## [UPX](https://upx.github.io/) to reduce the binary in approx 50%:

```
upx -9 hello_world.exe
```

---

```
      File size         Ratio      Format      Name
 --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
   40448 ->  20992      51.90%    win64/pe     hello_world.exe
```

Comment: a C hello word in TCC is 2 Kb, and does'nt use an executable compressor..