# Why is a C++ Hello World binary larger than the equivalent C binary?

Tags: c++, c, size

In his FAQ, Bjarne Stroustrup says that when compiled with gcc -O2, the file size of a hello world using C and C++ are identical.

Reference: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#Hello-world

I decided to try this, here is the C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the C++ version

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Here I compile, and the sizes are different:

```
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ ls
hello.c  hello.cpp
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ gcc -O2 hello.c -o c.out
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ g++ -O2 hello.cpp -o cpp.out
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 r00t r00t 8559 Sep  1 18:00 c.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 r00t r00t 8938 Sep  1 18:01 cpp.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 r00t r00t   95 Sep  1 17:59 hello.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 r00t r00t  117 Sep  1 17:59 hello.cpp
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ size c.out cpp.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1191     560       8    1759     6df c.out
   1865     608     280    2753     ac1 cpp.out
```

I replaced `std::endl` with `\n` and it made the binary smaller. I figured something this simple would be inlined, and am dissapointed it's not.

Also wow, the optimized assemblies have hundreds of lines of assembly output?  I can write hello world with like 5 assembly instructions using sys_write, what's up with all the extra stuff?  Why does C put some much extra on the stack to setup?  I mean, like 50 bytes of assembly vs 8kb of C, why?

Comment: No, he didn't say that. He said *"In 2004, I tested using gcc -O2 on a Unix and the two versions (iostreams and stdio) yielded identical sizes."*

Comment: What specifically is your question? Also, I think it's a bit strong to claim that Bjarne lied about this. It's possible that with an older compiler on an older system, the binaries did have the same size (even if on newer systems this isn't true.)

Comment: Now strip symbols...

Comment: 0/10 unoriginal trolling.

Comment: You could use the `size` command (`size c.out cpp.out`) to check the binary sizes — the code, the (initialized) data, the bss section (zero initialized data).  And ~500 bytes is not a lot of difference in size.

Comment: It's not at all "unclear what [he]'s asking", you unimaginative trolls. It's a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10981140/560648!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No it's not, the file size is 2 orders of magnitude different and it's on Windows. 400 KB is worth worrying about, 500 bytes is academic.

Comment: Despite OP having made some mistakes, this is a legitimate question with one or more legitimate technical answers. The size difference between the programs can be measured and accounted for.

Comment: If you want even more bloat in your helloworld, just add Boost.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking at a mix of information that's easily misinterpreted. The 8559 and 8938 byte file sizes are largely meaningless since they're mostly headers with symbol names and other misc information for at least minimal debugging purposes. The *somewhat* meaningful numbers are the `size(1)` output you added later:

```
r00t@wutdo:~/hello$ size c.out cpp.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1191     560       8    1759     6df c.out
   1865     608     280    2753     ac1 cpp.out
```

You could get a more detailed breakdown by using the `-A` option to `size`, but in short, the differences here are fairly trivial.

What's more interesting is that Bjarne Stroustrup never mentioned whether he was talking about static or dynamic linking. In your case, both programs are dynamic-linked, so the size differences have nothing to do with the actual size cost of stdio or iostream; you're just measuring the cost of the calling code, or (more likely, based on the other comments/answer) the base overhead of exception-handling support for C++. Now, there is a common claim that a static-linked C++ iostream-based hello world can be even smaller than a `printf`-based one, since the compiler can see exactly which overloaded versions of `operator<<` are used and optimize out unneeded code (such as expensive floating point printing), whereas `printf`'s use of format strings makes this difficult in the common case and impossible in general. However, I've never seen a C++ implementation where a static-linked iostream-based hello program could come anywhere near close to being as small as, much less smaller than, a `printf`-based one in C.

Answer (score 5):

I think he's treating the half kilobyte as a rounding error. Both are "9 kilobytes" and that's what you'll see in a typical file browser. They aren't exactly the same because, under the hood, the C and C++ libraries are quite different. If you're already familiar with your disassembler, you can see the details of the difference for yourself.

The "extra stuff" is for the sake of importing symbols from the standard library shlib, and handling C++ exceptions. Strangely enough, much of the GCC-compiled C executable is taken up by C++ exception handling tables. I've not figured out how to strip them using GCC.

`endl` *is* inlined, but it contains calls to print the `\n` character and flush the stream, which are not inlined. The difference in size is due to importing those from the standard library.

In truth, individual kilobytes seldom matter on any system with dynamically-loaded libraries. Self-contained code such as on an embedded system would need to include the standard library functionality it uses, and the C++ standard library tends to be heavier than its C counterpart — `<iostream>` vs. `<stdio.h>` in particular.

Comment: _"I've not figured out how to strip them using GCC"_ `-fno-exceptions` usually prevents using exceptions. There's also a weak function to override in the `stdlibc++` that provides the terminate (`terminate_handler` or so) code for exception handling.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Of course that's the first thing I tried :v) . Let me know if you find something that works. The issue isn't generating exceptions, it's providing support for calls to functions that use exceptions.

Comment: I would have to check my colleagues work, he did the trick omitting the standard uncatched exception handling code by overriding that mentioned weak function. I just don't remember the exact name for now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The cruft isn't executable code at all, it's the tables that tell the unwinding library how to interpret the stack.

Comment: If _the tables_ aren't referenced by any code, they won't be pulled from the linker, would they?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not how exception handling works. The tables are used by `libunwind`. I suggest you compile something like this "hello world," or even something simpler with no library calls, and then check the compiled size and run it through a disassembler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my colleague did that trick well. The challenge that was asked for was to use exceptions, but to remove any unnecessary overhead. And the main codesize bottleneck turned out to be that "`terminate_handler`" function. I'm not sure if this will help to reduce that code linked in via `stdlibc++`.