# Why does my hello world program take up 883KB?

Tags: c++

I have made a simple Hello World program in C++.

But, for some reasons it is taking up almost 900kb.

I have no idea why it is so big. I am using `-s`, `-Os` and `-Bdynamic` I am using **Code blocks**.

I tried this: [GCC C++ "Hello World" program -> .exe is 500kb big when compiled on Windows. How can I reduce its size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042773/gcc-c-hello-world-program-exe-is-500kb-big-when-compiled-on-windows-how)

**My program:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Yesterday i made a bigger program and it was only 21Kb.
Now every single of the executables are about 900Kb.

**Info**:
I tried to compile it myself using `g++ Hello.cpp -Bdynamic -s -Os` - Still the same size.

But when i compiled it using `printf` from `<stdio.h>` i got it to 21Kb.

I want to use `<iostream>`

[image: Sizes]

(It is an updated version of my post)

Comment: I recommend looking at what the executable consists of.

Comment: Looks like the dynamic libstdc++ is missing, static one used.